# last callback function acting weird

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="actions_container" id="message_form_container"> ...<input type="text" id="message" />... </div>
<div class="actions_container" id="coffee_form_container"> ...<input type="text" id="coffee_message" />... </div>
<div class="actions_container" id="network_form_container"> ...<input type="text" id="network_message" />... </div>   

    <select name="dropdown" id="select_action">

    <option value="message"> OPTION 1 </option>
    <option value="coffee"> OPTION 2 </option>
    <option value="network"> OPTION 3 </option>

    </select>
```

jQuery:

```
 $j('#select_action').bind('change', function(e) { 

        var current_val = $j('#select_action').val();


            //console.log("TESTING DROPDOWN CHANGE | BBBBB");
        if (current_val == 'message') {

            $j('.actions_container').slideUp('fast', function() {
            $j('#message_form_container').slideDown('slow', function() {

                    $j('#message_container_m2').slideUp('fast', function() {
                    $j('#message_container_m1 #message').val('');   
                    $j('#message_container_m1').slideDown('slow');

                    });
                });
            });
        } else if(current_val == 'coffee') {
            $j('.actions_container').slideUp('fast', function() {
            $j('#coffee_form_container').slideDown('slow', function() {

                    $j('#message_container_c2').slideUp('fast', function() {
                    $j('#message_container_c1 #coffee_message').val('');    
                    $j('#message_container_c1').slideDown('slow');

                    });
                });
            });
        } else if(current_val == 'network') {

            $j('.actions_container').slideUp('fast', function() {
            $j('#network_form_container').slideDown('slow', function() {

                    $j('#message_container_n2').slideUp('fast', function() {
                    $j('#message_container_n1 #network_message').val('');   
                    //$j('#message_container_n1').slideDown('slow');

                    });
                });
            });
        }


    });
```

Journeyman here.

the last case where if current_val == add_to_network .. makes the #network_form_container slide down twice. once it happens to the third it also happens to the 2nd .. until I select the 1st option..then the 2nd starts behaving normally again.

would also like to see how you would write this more efficiently, nothing very high level.

Comment: what are the `message_container_c2` elements

Comment: can you edit the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/svz88/1/ to have all the relevant elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you have given is not sufficient for a complete solution, but try something like

```
<div class="actions_container" id="message_form_container">...
    <input type="text" class="message" id="message" />...</div>
<div class="actions_container" id="coffee_form_container">...
    <input type="text" class="message" id="coffee_message" />...</div>
<div class="actions_container" id="network_form_container">...
    <input type="text" class="message" id="network_message" />...</div>
<select name="dropdown" id="select_action">
    <option value="message" data-target="#message_form_container">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="coffee" data-target="#coffee_form_container">OPTION 2</option>
    <option value="network" data-target="#network_form_container">OPTION 3</option>
</select>
```

then

```
var $cts = $j('.actions_container');
$j('#select_action').bind('change', function (e) {

    var current_val = $j('#select_action').val(),
        $selected = $(this).find('option:selected'),
        $target = $($selected.data('target')),
        $visible = $cts.filter(':visible');

    if ($visible.length) {
        $cts.filter(':visible').slideUp('fast').promise().done(function () {
            $target.slideDown('slow', function () {
                $target.find('input.message').val('')
            });
        })
    } else {
        $target.slideDown('slow', function () {
            $target.find('input.message').val('')
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/svz88/)